# Google reCAPTCHA V2 Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

Has anyone successfully used the Google reCAPTCHA V2's analytics feature?

According to Google FAQ, admin can check the daily pass and fail stats in admin console. It reports requests passed & failed, sessions completed, spam index and average response time. However, for me, it's showing 'this site's traffic is below the minimum required to display charts'.

I am testing reCAPTCHA in localhost and does not have a lot of traffic. However, Google does not expose how many of traffics are required to display charts.

If anyone has insight on number of traffics required to display charts, please share :). Also, is there additional implementation from client/server side to successfully use the analytics tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here. Used for weeks on `localhost` and production servers (both specified in the `Domains` admin configuration) but still empty analytics. Did you solved this?

Comment: @Yann39 Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone looking for answers to this, I was finally able to create analytics working for Google recaptcha.

I still do not understand why Google does not explicitly specify the traffic required to activate the analytics tool but after mocking around 100~110 recaptcha, the analytics tool was finally able to display some data.

The data from the tool is neat and easy to understand.